# Relativise introducing redundant up-directory ".."

Tags: java, file, nio

I'm copy files from a jar to a local folder.

- The jar is located at `a/b`.
- The folder (in the jar) I'm trying to extract is located at `b/c`
- The destination folder should be `z`, i.e. `a/b/c/x` -> `z/x`

When I use `c.relativize("x")` I get `../c/x` instead of `x`.

This is a problem when I then try to do: `z.resolve(c.relativize(x))`.

I get `z/../c/x` instead of `z/x`

How do I fix this issue?

I tried `z.resolve(c.relativize(x).normalise())` but get the same result

The jar is `b` in the folder `a`. `c` is a resource (folder) inside the jar `b`. `x` is a file inside the folder `c`.

Comment: What is the value of "c" in `c.relativize("x")? `

Comment: @garykwwong c is a `File` (folder) inside a `ZipFileSystem`

Comment: alright, but ... the problem is, how did you get the value of c in your program and assign the retrieved value to the Path API? did you make use of ... e.g. toURI() method?

Comment: As the resource folder `c` is inside a jar (which is a file), it is not a normal recognized file system path (e.g. /file, /dir/file, ... , /dir/dir/file), the API you used would affect the value you get for this 'c' ...

Comment: otherwise, you could only hard-code some logic to replace the ".." in the returned value of `c` before you proceed subsequent handling.

Comment: @garykwwong That's what I ended up doing

Answer (score 0):

- The jar is in folder A/B/
- The source folder path inside the jar is /b/c/ with file /b/c/xxx.yyy
- The destination folder is Z
- The destination file should have path: Z/xxx.yyy

So:

```
    Path sourceZip = Paths.get("/A/B/my.zip");
    URI sourceZipURI = URI.create("jar:" + sourceZip.toUri());

    Path targetFolder = Paths.get("/Z");

    Map<String, Object> senv = new HashMap<>();
    try (FileSystem sourceZipFS = FileSystems.newFileSystem(sourceZipURI, senv, null)) {
        Path folderInZip = sourceZipFS.getPath("/b/c");
        Files.list(folderInZip).forEach(p -> {
            Path target = targetFolder.resolve(folderInZip.relativize(p).toString());
            try {
                Files.createDirectories(target.getParent());
                Files.copy(p, target);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

The main issue was the reversal of `relativize`; not the first time I encountered the misunderstanding. `child.relativize(parent)` gives a `..` whereas `parent.relativize(child)` truncates the path.

To get the target path one needs to convert the source Path to a string, to prevent combining two different file systems.

(I did not take care of subdirectories.)

Comment: The jar is `b` in the folder `a`. `c` is a resource (folder) inside the jar `b`. `x` is a file inside the folder `c`.

Comment: Okay I think you can correct the 3 paths yourself. One could print the fibal paths first.

Comment: This solution isn't valid, because it's for a different use case. The implementation of my program is fine, it's this relativisation issue that I'm focused on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood the usage of `path.relativize(Path)`

According to https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize(java.nio.file.Path), there is a statement as below:

> Constructs a relative path between this path and a given path.

e.g.

```
Path pathA = Paths.get("a"); // i.e. /a or /anyDir/anySubDir/a
Path pathB = Paths.get("b"); // i.e. /b or /anyDir/anySubDir/b
pathA.relativize(pathB)
```

Assume the result is `../b`, what does it mean?

It is actually telling you: as you are inside directory `a`, if you want to access directory `b`, you need to access by this approach `cd ../b`.

`relativize(Path)` is helping to analyzing the relative path between the parent Path and the child Path (i.e. how to access from parent Path to child Path).

Alternatively, from your question, looks like you are preferring to "construct" the path instead of "analyzing" the relative path. `relativize(Path)` is not the one for this purpose.

So, which one, "construct" manually or "analyze", do you want to achieve?

Comment: No, you've misunderstood my question. `a` is the parent of `b`. They're not siblings. a.relativise(b) returns `../a/b` which is equivalent to `b` (what I want)